# Problems with implementing Interfaces in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, pure-virtual

I am trying to learn Design Patterns with C++. I am implementing the Program given in the first chapter of `OReilly's Head First Design Patterns` regarding the Duck problem. Please bear with me, it's quite a long question.

Anyways, I have tried to create the following 2 interfaces:

```
class QuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack() = 0 ;
};

class FlyBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void fly() = 0 ;
};
```

Now i have a Duck class, which needs to have instants of the above 2 classes. What I am doing is:

```
class Duck
{
public:
    FlyBehavior flyBehavior;
    QuackBehavior quackBehavior;
    Duck()
    {

    }

    virtual void display() = 0 ;
    void performQuack()
    {
        quackBehavior.quack() ;
    }

    void performFly()
    {
        flyBehavior.fly() ;
    }

    void swim()
    {
        std::cout << "All ducks swim!\n" ;
    }
};
```

I have also created classes that implement the interfaces:

```
class Quack: public QuackBehavior
{
    void quack()
    {
        std::cout << "QUACK!\n" ;
    }
};

class FlyWithWings: public FlyBehavior
{
    void fly()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm flying...\n" ;
    }
};
```

and likewise. I created a class inheriting the Duck class and my main method:

```
class MallardDuck: public Duck
{
public:
    MallardDuck()
    {
        quackBehavior = new Quack() ;
        flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings() ;
    }

    void display()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm a real duck\n" ;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Duck mallard = new MallardDuck() ;
    mallard.performFly() ;
    mallard.performQuack() ;
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I am compiling the program, I am getting a long list of errors. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance to people who actually read the complete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to implement pure virtual method:

```
virtual void quack() = 0 ;
```

When you declare an object normally, you can not `new` it. And when you declare it as a pointer you have to call its items by `->`.

```
QuackBehavior quackBehavior;
quackBehavior = new Quack() ;  // <------- ERROR, quackBehavior is not a pointer
```

and

```
Duck mallard = new MallardDuck(); // <------- ERROR, mallard is not a pointer
mallard.performFly() ; // <-------- ERROR, you must use -> instead of .
                       //           if mallard is a pointer
```

Finally, use this code:

```
class MallardDuck: public Duck
{
public:
    MallardDuck()
    {
    }

    void display()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm a real duck\n" ;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Duck *mallard = new MallardDuck() ;
    mallard->performFly() ;
    mallard->performQuack() ;

    ...

    delete mallard;
}
```

You're learning C++, after understanding pointers, it's good to know and use smart-pointers([`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) instead of bare pointers.

Comment: I'd say if he's just learning C++ he's better off not using smart pointers.  He has to learn how pointers really work at some point.  He'll have a better understanding of them if he uses them without crutches at first, and then moves on to using smart pointers where applicable later.  He'll then also have a better understanding of how smart pointers work, where they don't work, and their limitations than if he doesn't get practice using normal pointers at all.

Comment: Yes I have implemented the pure virtual function in my class. And the code is working fine now. Excellent way of helping me understand the concepts! :)

Answer (score 2):

`FlyBehavior/QuackBehavior` are abstract classes, you can't make them members of `Duck`, you have to use pointer instead(dynamic polymorphism dispatches through reference or pointer):

```
#include <memory>

class Duck
{
public:
    std::unique<FlyBehavior> flyBehavior;
    std::unique<QuackBehavior> quackBehavior;
//...
};


MallardDuck() : flyBehavior( new FlyWithWings()), quackBehavior(new Quack()) 
{ }
```

As `FlyBehavior/QuackBehavior` serve as abstract classes, you should make their destructor virtual.

```
class QuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack() = 0 ;
    virutal ~QuackBehavior() {}
};

class FlyBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void fly() = 0 ;
    virtual ~FlyBehavior() {}
};
```

Comment: Why on earth would you suggest using smart pointers to someone who doesn't know raw pointers?

Comment: @icepack: because this way you can avoid touching on all the subtleties of pointers. There are two schools of thought on how to teach C++: either as C *and then* ++ or as a brand new language. The brand new language school makes use of the Standard Library early on, and delve into the deepest corners afterward.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have an instance of an abstract class. You should have pointers to the base class instead of objects in `Duck`, otherwise you will get compilation errors.

It is also apparent from this calls:

```
quackBehavior = new Quack();
flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();
```

`new Quack()` and `new FlyWithWings()` both return pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In class `Duck`, abstract class member objects `flyBehavior`  and `quackBehavior` needs to be instantiated with their derived classes `FlyWithWings` and `Quack` in the constructor, meanwhile the members needs to be of type pointer to use such an inheritance scheme:

```
class Duck
{
public:
    FlyBehavior* flyBehavior;
    QuackBehavior* quackBehavior;
    Duck()
    {
          flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();
          quackBehavior = new Quack();
    }

    ~Duck()
    {
          delete flyBehavior;
          delete quackBehavior;
    }

    virtual void display() = 0 ;
    void performQuack()
    {
        quackBehavior.quack() ;
    }

    void performFly()
    {
        flyBehavior.fly() ;
    }

    void swim()
    {
        std::cout << "All ducks swim!\n" ;
    }
};
```

You'd also need virtual destructors in the base classes:

```
class QuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack() = 0 ;
    virtual ~QuackBehavior();
};

class FlyBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void fly() = 0 ;
    virtual ~FlyBehavior();

};
```

Comment: actually i don't want to initialize the `flyBehavior` and `quackBehavior` in the `Duck` class. I want to initialize them in the `MallardDuck` class.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring a function as pure virtual like this:

```
virtual void display() = 0 ;
```

, you're effectively making the class it belongs to, abstract. Abstract means it can never be instantiated. You can never create instances of type of abstract class. Get rid of = 0 if you want to be able to have Duck objects.